# Snell's Law- Extraordinary ray

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, geometric-optics

I applied the snell's law to find the angle of refraction of the Ordinary and Extraordinary ray. And I got the correct answer 3.51. But I know my approach to the question is wrong because I applied the snell's law to the extraordinary rays that do not follow the snell's law. But I still don't understand how I got the correct answer. Any guidance on analysing the extraordinary rays in this context would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a double-refractive birefringent materials like calcite,- Snell's law *does apply* for the rays of different polarization, like [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence) :

> According to Snell's law of refraction, the two angles of refraction are governed by the **effective refractive index of each of these two polarizations**. This is clearly seen, for instance, in the Wollaston prism which separates incoming light into two linear polarizations using prisms composed of a birefringent material such as calcite.

That's why we can calculate the answer to the problem as being:

$$ \arcsin\left(\frac{n_{air}}{n_e}~\sin(\theta_1)\right) − \arcsin\left(\frac {n_{air}}{n_o}~\sin(\theta_1)\right) $$

Which when evaluated will give about $3.5^\circ$ angle separation between $\text{o/e}$ rays.